# Understanding group by MapReduce in spark (python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, rdd

I am trying a small program where I am considering an employee dataset and trying to calculate sum of salaries distributed in various departments. I have a reproducible example.

```
 emp_list=[(u'ACC', [u'101', u'a', u'ACC', u'1000']),
 (u'SALES', [u'102', u'b', u'SALES', u'2000']),
 (u'IT', [u'103', u'c', u'IT', u'3000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'104', u'd', u'ACC', u'4000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'105', u'e', u'ACC', u'5000']),
 (u'HR', [u'106', u'f', u'HR', u'6000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'107', u'g', u'ACC', u'7000']),
 (u'FIN', [u'108', u'h', u'FIN', u'8000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'109', u'k', u'ACC', u'9000']),
 (u'HR', [u'1010', u'l', u'HR', u'10000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'1011', u'm', u'ACC', u'11000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'1012', u'n', u'ACC', u'12000']),
 (u'FIN', [u'1013', u'o', u'FIN', u'13000']),
 (u'IT', [u'1014', u'p', u'IT', u'14000'])]

emp=sc.parallelize(emp_list)

emp.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x[3]+y[3]).take(10)
```

Output I am getting is :

```
[(u'ACC', u'00'),
 (u'HR', u'600010000'),
 (u'FIN', u'800013000'),
 (u'SALES', [u'102', u'b', u'SALES', u'2000']),
 (u'IT', u'300014000')]
```

Can anybody please explain me why I am getting strange values for `ACC` and `SALES` departments. I want to see the concatenated salaries for these two as well.

Comment: I want concatenated salaries because that means salaries get aggregated and can be summed up by just converting string to float/int.

Comment: Just one clue: if I have two records from `SALES` i get the concatenated results. But what I want is if I have just one record for a key e.g. `SALES` I should just get the value associated with it. i.e. `2000` and not the whole record.

Answer (score 4):

You get strange values because logic of your function is invalid. If you use Scala instead of Python this wouldn't even compile. When you apply `reduceByKey` LHS and RHS and return type should be of the same type:

```
reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

and `func` should be associative.

In your case types don't match (input is a list and return type is a string) and function is not associative. To understand what is going on lets consider two different cases:

1. Only one value per key. Since `func` is not applied you get this value as an output. Hence `(u'SALES', [u'102', u'b', u'SALES', u'2000'])`
2. Multiple values per key. Lets take a subset of values from `ACC` as an example and assume order of operations is defined as follows

   ```
   (
     # 1st partition
     ([u'101', u'a', u'ACC', u'1000'], [u'104', u'd', u'ACC', u'4000']),
     # 2nd partition
     ([u'105', u'e', u'ACC', u'5000'], [u'107', u'g', u'ACC', u'7000'])
   )
   ```

   After the first application of the `func` we get:

   ```
   (
      u'10004000',
      ([u'105', u'e', u'ACC', u'5000'], [u'107', u'g', u'ACC', u'7000'])
   )
   ```

   After the second application of the `func` we get

   ```
   (
      u'10004000',
      u'50007000'
   )
   ```

   And finally

   ```
   u'00'
   ```

   In practice parenthesizing can vary depending on configuration so you can get different outputs.

To get correct results you should use `aggregateByKey` / `combineByKey`, `map` + `reduce` as suggested by @alexs or `map` followed by `groupByKey` and `mapValues`. The last one should be the most efficient approach here since it doesn't require intermediate objects:

```
emp.mapValues(lambda x: x[3]).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda xs: "".join(xs))
```

For reference the same thing using `aggregateByKey`:

```
from operator import add

rdd.aggregateByKey("", lambda acc, x: acc + x[3], add)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. You saved me!! :)

Comment: Can you also refer me to some documentation where I can see the various lambda prototypes for various RDD methods. Like for reduceByKey method, lambda should be like `func: (V, V) ⇒ V`. In pyspark  docs they refer the lambda just as `func` whithout any spec.

Comment: my lambda function input x and y are list of string and I tried to return list of string from lambda function like this.. `emp.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : [x[3]+y[3]]).take(10)` and it doesn't work. I would appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain how it is possible to get the results you see.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should work:

```
emp.map(lambda k, v: (k, v[3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y).take(10)
```

Though I don't have a Spark instance to try it out

Comment: Thanks!! This worked with slight modification `emp.map(lambda v: (v[0], v[1][3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y).take(10)` but drawback is we lost other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that when you are reducing, the elements of the reduction need to maintain the same structure the first time the reduce sees them and all the other times as well. So here is the way to do it in your example:

```
emp_list=[(u'ACC', [u'101', u'a', u'ACC', u'1000']),
 (u'SALES', [u'102', u'b', u'SALES', u'2000']),
 (u'IT', [u'103', u'c', u'IT', u'3000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'104', u'd', u'ACC', u'4000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'105', u'e', u'ACC', u'5000']),
 (u'HR', [u'106', u'f', u'HR', u'6000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'107', u'g', u'ACC', u'7000']),
 (u'FIN', [u'108', u'h', u'FIN', u'8000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'109', u'k', u'ACC', u'9000']),
 (u'HR', [u'1010', u'l', u'HR', u'10000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'1011', u'm', u'ACC', u'11000']),
 (u'ACC', [u'1012', u'n', u'ACC', u'12000']),
 (u'FIN', [u'1013', u'o', u'FIN', u'13000']),
 (u'IT', [u'1014', u'p', u'IT', u'14000'])]

emp=sc.parallelize(emp_list)
print emp.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : (1,1,1,x[3] + y[3]))\
.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][3])).collect()
>> [(u'ACC', u'100040005000700090001100012000'), (u'HR', u'600010000'),\
 (u'FIN', u'800013000'), (u'SALES', u'2000'), (u'IT', u'300014000')]
```

Comment: Yes, though trivial approach, but this works. This approach is just useful for handling keys with just one record. for e.g. `SALES` here.