# Reduce by multiple combinations of key in Spark Streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a spark job which listens to a kinesis stream and does some aggregations on it. The RDDs in DStream have structure as follows - 
{"name":"abc", "sex": "M", "age":25, "points": 2}, .....

I want to calculate sum of all points across different combinations of keys ie, name, sex, age, sex_age, name_sex, etc

The way i am doing it right now is as follows -

```
count_by_name = instream.map(lambda x: (x.get('name'), x.get('points'))).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x[1]+y[1])
count_by_age = instream.map(lambda x: (x.get('age'), x.get('points')).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x[1] + y[1])
count_by_age_and_sex = instream.map(lambda x: (x.get('age')+'_'+x.get('sex'), x.get('points'))).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x[1]+y[1])
```

and so on for each key. But this is clearly not a elegant way to this, since there can be more keys and more combinations. And i will have to write a separate reducer for each combination.

Is there any better way to this which can help is parallelization or modularity of code?

Comment: You could have a look at pandas library that does all sort of grouping and computations

Comment: What you're _doing right now_ doesn't look like a valid Spark code...

Comment: @zero323 its python code, considering "instream" is a Dstream. Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Well, it looks like more or less (excluding `byKey` part) problem like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34873841/1560062)  (it is not associative s) but to be honest I am not even sure what you're trying to do here. Did you mean `reduceByKey`?

Comment: @zero323 thanks, edited the question with reduceByKey

Comment: Could you please explain how you will use it afterwards? As it looks similar to OLAP scenarios where you want to store lowest level of granularity and then aggregate at later stages only those combinations  that are actually needed